# Pig Script without load

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie to Pig. I am trying to figure out how to define a bag or tuple with hard coded values, without loading data from a file. Every example that I have encountered with starts with:

a = LOAD '/file/name' using PigStorage(',');

or something similar. I just want to create a tuple or bag like this:

a = <1,2,3>;

Is it possible to use hard coded values for testing purposes?

Thanks.

Comment: Great question ! You might want to format edit it though, in order to format your code and to add the pig version you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is impossible to just create a tuple or bag in Pig like this in the current version (0.15.0).

My suggestion is to create a simple text file with a few values separated by commas, and use the following command:

```
a = LOAD '/path' using PigStorage(',');
```

The text file should look something like:

```
1,2,3
```

Hopefully in future versions they will release some way to accomplish creating a tuple or bag with a single command.

Good Luck practicing Pig!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to declare hard coded values with PigLatin itself.
If you wish to test your scripts, you may want to use [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html). This will let you declare what you want in the language of your choice.